# Android listview add subitems

Tags: android, listview, submenu

i want add subitem in a listview. This is my code

```
ArrayList<String> mAllData;
    private   String [] cognomi = {
      //my string
    };
public void setData() {
    mAllData = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAdapter = new MySimpleSearchAdapter(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < cognomi.length; i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem(cognomi[i]);
        mAllData.add(cognomi[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pre-defined android layout for this: http://www.javajirawat.com/2013/03/android-listview-tutorial_12.html

Comment: If you want to do that, look at this website to make a custom listview: http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html